# Nuxt-content not working with asyncData in a component

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, nuxt-content

I'm trying to fetch content from my `content/blog` folder but I can't make it work in the `components/menu.vue` page since it's a component ?

This is working in the `page/index.vue` but not in `components/menu.vue`. Why?

I'm new to all this and maybe I'm doing something wrong here, maybe I'm not able to fetch content from a component... I don't know.

```html
<template>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="articles">
          <div class="article" v-for="article of articles" :key="article">
            <nuxt-link :to="{ name: 'slug', params: { slug: article.slug } }">
              <div class="article-inner">
                <img :src="require(`~/assets/${article.img}`)" alt="" />
                <div class="detail">
                  <h3>{{ article.title }}</h3>
                  <p>{{ article.description }}</p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </nuxt-link>
          </div>
     </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  async asyncData ({ $content, params }) {
    const articles = await $content('blog', params.slug)
      .only(['title', 'description', 'img', 'slug'])
      .sortBy('createdAt', 'asc')
      .fetch()
    console.log('bongo')
    return {
      articles
    }
  },
  data () {
    return {
      num: this.$route.name
    }
  },
  computed: {
    currentRouteName () {
      return this.$route.name
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Hi, why did you deleted your previous question? I was about to answer how to fix the issue.

Comment: Sorry kissu! I solved the issue all by myself, it was a typo... I said `import Opened from './Opened.vue'` instead of `./Opened.vue`
Thank you very much for the support actually. It's very helpful ! :)

Comment: The issue was not related to the async call you had? Interesting.

Comment: the async call was working, I just need to write my code better... haha.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As written here: https://nuxtjs.org/docs/features/data-fetching#async-data

> asyncData is only available for pages and you don't have access to this inside the hook.

So yes you can use `asyncData` only in a page.
An alternative would be to use a non-blocking `fetch()` hook as shown here: https://nuxtjs.org/docs/features/data-fetching#accessing-the-fetch-state

Comment: Thanks kissu for your help. Will dig into that since I have no clue on how to achieve that haha.

Comment: @damian it's just a bit different in the syntax, not a huge deal. You can create a new question if you'd like.

Comment: I nailed it by copying the result of this https://github.com/nuxt/content/issues/97
I would prefer to save some more important questions for later haha. Thanks a lot for your fast help.

Comment: I was wondering, since you are helping me a lot, if I could have a little help in private for that specific website? Thanks :)

Comment: @Aurore my bio is a place where you could find some info on how to reach me.